# Mean correlation within cluster

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I'd like to calculate the mean correlation within a cluster and understand if it's significantly >0. I'm using packages 'geomorph' and 'paleomorph'.

```
#Simulate an array
A <- array(rep(1:36, by = 4), dim = c(12, 3, 4))
#Load 'geomorph' package and superimpose coordinates
test.gpa <- gpagen(A, print.progress = FALSE)
#Load 'paleomorph' and generate covariance and correlation matrices
cvmatrix<-dotcvm(test.gpa$coords)
corrmatrix<-dotcorr(test.gpa$coords)
```

Then I do a clustering with Ward method and euclidean distance, using the cvmatrix and I get a dendrogram. This part is not the problem, so I'll go directly to what I want. I would like to calculate the mean correlation between the elements of each cluster. Since clustering methods will mandatorily produce clusters, I'd like to know if the elements of my clusters are correlated (I mean, if the clusters are valid).

I believe this might not be very complicated, given that I have all the elements. I just don't know how to do it in R. I tried to do the clustering with p-values for each cluster, with pvclust(), but I'm following a paper in which the authors test the significance of the clusters by assessing the mean correlation of the elements within each cluster. I'd like to compare this method with the one from pvclust().

Comment: To match a paper, you may do best to contact the authors?

Comment: They are kind of slow to answer and I guess it's just a matter of coding. I sent an e-mail anyway but no answer yet. I just wanted to know if anyone else knew what this means, 'cause I haven't seen this "within cluster mean correlation" in other papers...